# How can I monitor read/write requests on a CIFS filesystem?

Tags: linux, cifs

Is there a way to monitor read/write requests on a CIFS-mountend filesystem? I have a container using Azure Files with a filesystem mounted via CIFS. My read/write transaction costs on Azure are higher than expected, and I would like to see what processes are reading/writing files on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `fatrace` which can monitor all disk io, or with `-c` only those for the filesystem of the current directory.

```bsh
$ cd /tmp; sudo fatrace -c -t
11:27:55.404188 bash(28844): O /tmp
11:27:55.404188 bash(28844): R /tmp
11:27:55.404188 bash(28844): R /tmp
11:27:55.404574 bash(28844): C /tmp
11:28:01.711543 upsc(32404): CO /tmp
11:28:03.044996 bash(32405): O /tmp/output
11:28:03.070504 conky(32405): RO /tmp/conky
11:28:03.071178 conky(32405): C /tmp/conky
11:28:03.072308 conky(32405): W /tmp/output
11:28:06.131741 unknown(32405): CW /tmp/output
```

The events are shown by their first letter: Open Close Read Write

For simple overall r/w per second statistics there is `cifsiostat`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!